# How to change text color in mat-button using custom theme

Tags: css, sass, angular-material

In using this [document](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-complete-guide-to-angular-material-themes-4d165a9d24d1).  In attempting to change the text color in a mat-button I added a theme.scss to 
the css project.  Here is the theme.scss code:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 700, 300, 900);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange, A200);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, 
$candy-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

This is the html file:

```
 <button  mat-raised-button color="accent" routerLink="/">Home</button>
```

The accent color shows the expected accent, mat-light-blue, color.  The text inside the button is still gray.  The A400 is not displaying white as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply light-theme custom settings for background and foreground(text colors). Insert this before applying your custom theme and use your color values instead of values in my example:

```
$mat-light-theme-background: (
  background:               $your_background,
  status-bar:               $light-bg-darker-20,
  app-bar:                  $light-bg-darker-5,
  hover:                    $dark-bg-alpha-4,
  card:                     $light-bg-lighter-5,
  dialog:                   $light-bg-lighter-5,
  tooltip:                  $dark-bg-tooltip,
  disabled-button:          $dark-bg-alpha-12,
  raised-button:            #e5e5e5,
  focused-button:           $dark-focused,
  selected-button:          $light-bg-darker-20,
  selected-disabled-button: $light-bg-darker-30,
  disabled-button-toggle:   $light-bg-darker-10,
  unselected-chip:          $light-bg-darker-10,
  disabled-list-option:     $light-bg-darker-10,
);

$mat-light-theme-foreground: (
  base:              $cdm-grey,
  divider:           $dark-dividers,
  dividers:          $dark-dividers,
  disabled:          $dark-disabled-text,
  disabled-button:   rgba($dark-text, 0.26),
  disabled-text:     $dark-disabled-text,
  elevation:         black,
  secondary-text:    $dark-accent-text,
  hint-text:         $dark-disabled-text,
  accent-text:       $dark-accent-text,
  icon:              $dark-accent-text,
  icons:             $dark-accent-text,
  text:              $dark-primary-text,
  slider-min:        $dark-primary-text,
  slider-off:        rgba($dark-text, 0.26),
  slider-off-active: $dark-disabled-text,
);
```

Comment: where would you use these variable? When answering pls try to make your examples precise. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is showing the same as expected. (mat-light-blue, A400) will have black as foreground color. I will suggest you to use range between 700 to 900 for getting white as foreground.

You can refer to below link for the reference for material design color pallate.
https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#tools-for-picking-colors

And if you want to use the same color(A400) with white foreground, you can to do that with your own styling.

```
.mat-raised-button{
   color: white !important;
 }
```